# how to insert and retrieve data from cassandra DB in XML format using JAVA?

Tags: java, xml, cassandra

I want an example program on how to insert and retrieve data from cassandra database in XML format using JAVA API.I have tried this with JSON format that worked fine. But I am new to XML format.Can someone help me get solved with this issue.

Comment: If you are able to store and retrieve json formatted blobs, why do you think xml would be handled any different?

Comment: Hi, I didnot use blobs  when I have inserted data into cassandra in JSON and if i retrieve using SELECT statement it is showing the output as normal SQL one.I just want to try with XML also so could you help me

Comment: I just saw, Cassandra has built-in JSON support. So I guess for XML you have to do a little more effort.

Comment: import com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster;
import com.datastax.driver.core.Row;
import com.datastax.driver.core.Session;

public class CasandarConnect {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String serverIP = "127.0.0.1";
    String keyspace = "mykeyspace";

    Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder()
      .addContactPoints(serverIP)
      .build();

    Session session = cluster.connect(keyspace);

    String cqlStatement = "INSERT INTO users JSON '{\"id\":123 , \"age\":21 ,\"state\":\"AB\"}'";
    session.execute(cqlStatement);
}

Comment: If I use select command the output id,age and state are displayed

Comment: Spring seems to have XML support for Cassandra http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-cassandra/

Comment: I am sorry, I cannot be of further help due to my lack of experience with cassandra and the datastax java driver. But I upvoted your Q to attract more knowledgable users. Good luck for you and welcome to SO. You may rephrase the question though: "I want an example program" doesn't sound too much like you did actually your own research. I recommend also adding to the question what you have tried even if the attempt failed. A good guideline is given here: [ask]

Comment: ok thank you i wiil try

Comment: Is this the command ---> insert into users (id int primary key, age int , state text) values (123, 21,'AB'); which is used to insert data into cassandra DB in XML format